# Copy dynamic Excel range to Word as figure

Tags: vba, excel

I´m trying to copy as figures to a Word document an Excel dynamic range that changes from case to case.

The first worksheet will be where the user will place the inputs. Than on the fourth worksheet some calculations for each row of the inputs will be performed. What i would like to do is to copy to an word document the content of the fourth worksheet until the last input row. The problem is that the last input row number will change form case to case.

Another difficulty is the fact that each Word page only has space for 45 lines so if the input goes beyond that number it would need to be splitt in multiples pages.

I have code that works for a static range and I would like to change to also work with a dynamic range.

```
Sub copyword()
   Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object, Rng As Object
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim n As Integer

   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

   'see if Word is already open
   On Error Resume Next
   Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
   On Error GoTo 0

   'not open - create a new instance and add a document
   If objWord Is Nothing Then
       Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
       objWord.Visible = True
       objWord.documents.Add
   End If

   Set objDoc = objWord.activedocument
   Set Rng = objWord.Selection

   Worksheets(2).Activate
   ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
   wb.Worksheets(2).Range("A1:O47").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
   Rng.Paste
   Rng.typeparagraph
   ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview

   Worksheets(2).Activate
   ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
   wb.Worksheets(2).Range("U1:AI47").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
   Rng.Paste
   Rng.typeparagraph
   ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the last row with data in column A (not tested):

```
Sub copyword()
   Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object, Rng As Object
   Dim wb As Workbook, n As Integer, lr As Long

   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   On Error Resume Next 'see if Word is already open
   Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
   On Error GoTo 0

   If objWord Is Nothing Then   'not open - create a new instance and add a document
       Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
       objWord.Visible = True
       objWord.documents.Add
   End If
   Set objDoc = objWord.activedocument
   Set Rng = objWord.Selection
   With wb.Worksheets(2)

      'determine last row *****************************************
      lr = .Cells("A" & .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

      .Activate
         ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
         'use last row *********************************************************
         .Range("A1:O" & lr).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
         Rng.Paste
         Rng.typeparagraph
         ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
      .Activate
         ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
         'use last row **********************************************************
         .Range("U1:AI" & lr).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
         Rng.Paste
         Rng.typeparagraph
         ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
   End With
End Sub
```